# String::ShellQuote: when do I need `shell_quote`?

Tags: perl, shell, system, argument-passing

Does it make sense to use `shell_qoute` from [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aShellQuote) when I pass the arguments to `system` this way?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use String::ShellQuote qw(shell_quote);

my $file = shift;
my $argument = shift;

$file = shell_quote $file;
$argument = shell_quote $argument;

system( 'some_command', '--verbose', '-o', $file, $argument );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it doesn't. If you invoke `system` as

```
system LIST
```

then it doesn't invoke the shell. Shell meta-characters have no special meaning. So you must not quote your arguments, or else it gives the wrong results.

One needs to quote if `system` is invoked as

```
system SCALAR
```

where SCALAR might be something like `ls file name with spaces` and the argument to `ls` is a single file name that has spaces.